# Invalid given probability question?

Tags: probability

My math textbook asks:

**Two fair dice are tossed. Find each probability.** $P($less than $5$ or greater than $3)$

After doing some math:

$P($sum of less than $5$ or greater than $3)=P($sum less than $5) + P($sum greater than $3)=\dfrac{6}{36}+\dfrac{33}{36}=\dfrac{39}{36}=\dfrac{13}{12}$

I get $\dfrac{13}{12}$. From what I have heard, you can not have a probability $> 1$. Did I do the math wrong, or is the question invalid, or should I just "round" to $1$? (Since $1$ would make sense)

Comment: Hint: The event "less than 5" contains some of the same events as "greater than 3". What is the probability of a single number, say, 4? Is the probability the same for each number? If so, what can you do with that knowledge?

Comment: Is this written correctly?  Every outcome is less than $5$ or greater than $3$ so the answer is $1$.  Or did you mean "and" instead of "or"?

Comment: @lulu No, it is written correctly. It's a pretty strange question

Comment: Then the answer is $1$, for trivial reasons.

Comment: In short $P(\underbrace{A\cup B}_{\text{or}})=P(A)+P(B)\color{red}{-P(\underbrace{A\cap B}_{\text{and}})}$

Comment: @MCMastery Actually, it’s a very good question. It’s set up so that when you make the error of overcounting the intersection of the two events, as you did, you get an obviously incorrect answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These events are not disjoint so you can't just can't add them. You need to subtract of the probability that the sum is less than $5$ and greater than $3$ namely the probability that the sum equals $4$. This probability is $3/36$ by enumerating the possibilities.

Comment: Thank you (such a silly mistake ;-;)

Comment: Of course, you could avoid all calculation by noting that **every** real number is less than $5$ or greater than $3$.

Comment: @lulu I said OP needs to subtract off the probability given his current attempt at solving the problem. Taking off $3/36$ we find that the probability is $39/36-36/36=1$ which is expected.